# Combobox binding does not update

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind a combobox to a value in data set I navigate through using a binding navigator.

I have a form, and some textboxes binded to a dataset through a binding navigator.

the binding to a textbox is simple:

```
this.catActualTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.myBindingSource, "CatActual", true))
```

It works perfect, but I need to change one of theese textboxes with a combobox. The textboxes show numbers (keys) and I want to show the related descriptions (values). So I use a combobox. I load the combobox with a DataTable, wich has  two colums "IdCatActual" (the keys) and "Descrip" (the values). It shows correctly in the form, but it does not update when navigate:

```
this.catActualComboBox1.DataSource = myDataTable;
this.catActualComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Descrip";
this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedItem", this.myBindingSource, "CatActual"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

I was using the wrong porperty. I must bind "SelectedValue" property instead "SelectedItem" property.